# Difference between OnlyOnRanToCompletion and NotOnFaulted?

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask, task

These two values are from the [TaskContinuationOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx) enumeration. I'm a bit unsure of which one to use.

Another pair I'm confused between is `NotOnRanToCompletion` and `OnlyOnFaulted`.

The wording is a bit confusing to me and each value from each pair seem to function equally. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes: if something is canceled, it's neither faulted nor ran-to-completion; so it *would* be processed by `NotOnRanToCompletion` but not by `OnlyOnFaulted`.

So:

```
NotOnRanToCompletion | NotOnFaulted == OnlyOnCancelled
NotOnCanceled        | NotOnFaulted == OnlyOnRanToCompletion
NotOnRanToCompletion | NotOnCanceld == OnlyOnFaulted
```

Comment: so if you have event handler attached to both NotOnRanToCompletion and OnlyOnCancelled, which one will be called if the task is cancelled? OR it really does not make any sense to handle both events at the same time??

Answer (score 4):

`OnlyOnFaulted` means that the continuation will run if the antecedent task throws an exception that is not handled by the task itself, *unless* the task was canceled.

`NotOnRanToCompletion` means that the continuation will *not* run if the task ran to completion, that is to say it *will* run if the task threw an exception, *or* if it was canceled.

So to summarize, if you want your continuation to run if the task is canceled or threw an exception, use `NotOnRanToCompletion`. If you want it to run only if it threw an exception but not if it is canceled, use `OnlyOnFaulted`.

Comment: so if you have event handler attached to both NotOnRanToCompletion and  OnlyOnCancelled, which one will be called if the task is cancelled?     OR it really does not make any sense to handle both events at the same time???